# How to save string with code page 1250 into a file in Dart?

Tags: encoding, dart

I would like to save and read a string with Windows-1250 code page, but I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is to write an [Encoding](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:convert.Encoding) which is a [Converter](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/converters-and-codecs/).

You need to map the incoming Unicode characters to their corresponding Windows-1250 equivalents (and probably throw, if it contains characters that are outside its range). You can take the Iso-Latin-1 encoder as a starting point: [latin1.dart](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/1.7/dart/sdk/lib/convert/latin1.dart)